# No cart items in quote

Tags: magento-2.0.2

I am preparing module which displays cart item list on every page. I have a problem with retrieving cart items from session quote. When I am on page with cart ([magento_url]/checkout/cart) everything is fine and I get all items which are currently in the cart. But when I move to any other page (e.g. product list or product detail) the expression `$this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();` gives me an empty array (I have the cart nonempty :-).

I use this block to get items:

```
<?php

namespace <VENDOR>\FootCart\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;

class FootCart extends Template
{
    protected $checkoutSession;

    public function __construct(
            Template\Context $context,
            \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
            array $data = array()) 
    {

        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;

        parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }

    public function getCartItems()
    {
        $items = $this->checkoutSession->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();   

        return $items;
    }

}
```

And in my template .phtml file I use the above function `getCartItems()` to list the items. This function returns empty array when I am on any page except the cart page.

To display the module on every page I use default.xml:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-content">
            <block class="<VENDOR>\FootCart\Block\FootCart" name="footcart-footcart" template="<VENDOR>_FootCart::footcart.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Thank you for any help!

Comment: the same on 2.1

Answer (score 0):

having the same problem like this

try using `Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart`

assign to your construct

```
public function __construct(
    Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart $cart
)
{
    $this->cart = $cart;
}
```

and call `$this->cart->getSectionData()`

you will get list of array, look in the `items` key

hope this helps you

got this reference from this : [How is a mini-cart rendered?](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/905)